# C++: Printing out map values

Tags: c++, for-loop, printing, dictionary

So I have a map like this:

```
map<long, MusicEntry> Music_Map;
```

MusicEntry contains strings of (name, artist, size, and date added)

My question is how can print, how do I print out all the data in my map? I have tried doing...

```
   for(auto it = Music_Map.cbegin(); it!= Music_Map.cend(); ++it)
    cout << it-> first << ", " <<  it-> second << "\n";
```

I think the problem is occuring that it can't compile and read second aka MusicEntry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an `std::ostream operator<< (std::ostream&, const MusicEntyr&)` so that you can do this kind of thing:

```
MusicEntry m;
std::cout << m << std::endl;
```

With that in place, you can print the map's `second` fields. Here's a simplified example:

```
struct MusicEntry
{
  std::string artist;
  std::string name;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const MusicEntry& m)
{
  return o << m.artist << ", " << m.name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is fine, but you need to implement

```
std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MusicEntry& e)
{
    return os << "(" << e.name << ", " << ... << ")";
}
```

and you probably need to declare the above a `friend` in `MusicEntry` to access the private (or protected) data of `MusicEntry`:

```
class MusicEntry
{
    // ...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MusicEntry& e);
};
```

This is, of course, not needed if the data is public or if you use public getters. You can find a lot more information in the [operator overloading FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706).